# Framework added via PODS -> framework not found JumioCore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I have been trying to debug this for a few days already. I am not able to find a solution.

I have installed JumioMobileSDK via cocoapods. However, when I run the project I am getting an error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you opening your project's workspace instead of xcproj?

Comment: From the Workspace. I see all the my projects and pods project.

Comment: Do you have multiple targets in your project?

Comment: I have multiple pods added and all are visible (mainly they are not framework pods. They are actual classes .swift or .h/m. JumioMobileSdk is the only Framework pod installed.

Answer (score 0):

**First check your dependencies and update CocoaPods**, then close your current project and **open the .xcworkspace** created in your project folder.

If that doesn't work...

**Show the Report navigator** (8. tab in left navigator of Xcode) and **check the report**. It should give you some info what is going on like:

```
framework not found Pods_[PODFILE_OLD_ABSTRACT_TARGET_NAME].
```

If it keeps the framework with the old name that no longer exists (next to the new one), remove it.

You have an awesome day! Contact me if you need any further help!

Comment: I have checked all dependecies and cocoaPods is up to date. The report navigator also shows the same message as above: framework not found jumiocore.

Comment: Them it is not properly installed as I said, update/install Cocoa-pods again dependencies for that project (You didn't mention you did) please do...